# Storing a config setting against a class in SilverStripe

Tags: class, configuration, silverstripe

I have a class extending DataObject, let's call it ExtendedDataObject, that I want to have a single config setting for; in particular, an email address. ie I want to store one email address for the class, not one per instance. If I have multiple classes extending my ExtendedDataObject, then each class would need a separate email address.

Ideally I'd like to keep the code separate in an ExtendedDataObject.php file so that I can use it for multiple projects. Can I add a $Class.Email property to the site config somehow perhaps?

Comment: Do the email addresses need to be editable in the CMS? Or would having them configurable in a yml config file suffice?

Comment: @3dgoo would be good to know how to make them editable in the CMS for future projects, but in a yml config file will be fine for my current project. I see an answer has been added saying how to add it to a yml file :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the YML version you can add them to `mysite/_config/emails.yml`:

```
---
Name: dataobjectemails
After:
  - 'framework/*'
  - 'cms/*'
---
ExtendedDataObject:
  email: your.first.email@example.com
AnotherExtendedDataObject:
  email: your.second.email@example.com
```

And you can fetch them via `Config`:

```
Config::inst()->get($yourClassName, 'email');
```

Comment: Thanks! This will solve the problem for my current project... I'll leave this open a bit longer in case someone can suggest a way to easily make the value editable in the CMS.

Comment: @HighlyIrregular As this answers your question id mark it as solved still.